# Convert this from NFA to DFA

Tags: dfa, nfa

Construct a DFA (with alphabet {a,b}) that is equivalent to the following NFA:
[image]

My conversion is below, but it appears to be wrong, can you help me explain why?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any DFA state that includes NFA state 5 must also include NFA state 2, due to the epsilon transition.  You have a DFA state labelled just 5, which is thus wrong -- it should be 2,5 (and be merged with the other 2,5 state as a result).

You also forgot to label the edge from 2,3,5 to 4,6 (should be b).

Comment: Hi there, I have updated my DFA, but it still seems to be wrong.(maybe something to do with the empty string input on state 5)

Comment: 1 should be an accepting state -- other than that it looks corret to me...